# Bug with ç character in Stack Exchange Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I search for a job using the following query:

> français

I get the following result. I'm using a French build of Chrome 39 with Unicode UTF-8 encoding. I've not been able to try other characters or browsers.

[image: In the search result the ç character has disappeared]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it. Thank you for your report!

[image]

*Bien à vous,*